# Math? IF Statements. Multiple scenarios

Tags: math, if-statement

This is not high level Math, but I am struggling to apportion the appropriate amounts to my upsell types.

```
Type            Revenue  Sales  Units
1st Position    24       3      3
2nd Position1   10              2
2nd Position2   5               1
```

Only my 1st positions count toward the return per sale values and they include the revenue of my 2nd positions that were generated from that sale.

IMPORTANT NOTE: If the return per sale value is greater than or equal to 12 I must apply a split for the amount over 12.  My less than 12 value is *0.6 of the revenue, my greater than 12 value is *0.6 of amount less than 12 and *0.4 of amount over.

```
IF TotalRev/1st Position Units < 12 THEN TotalRev*.6 ELSE 7.2+(((TotalRev)/1stPositionUnits)-12)*.4)*1stPositionUnits = Total Revenue To Company.

IF (24+10+5)/3 < 12
THEN (24+10+5)*.6
ELSE ((.6*12)+((((24+10+5)/3)-12)*.4))*3
Net Revenue = 22.8
Net Return Per Sale = (Net Revenue/1st Position Units) = (22.8/3) = 7.6
```

Now I want to determine how much of the 1st position revenue contributed to the 7.6, how much of the 2nd position1 revenue and how much of the 3rd position...

My Attempt:

```
(1st Position Revenue/Total Revenue)*Net Return Per sale = (24/(24+10+5))*7.6 = 4.68
(2nd Position1 Revenue/Total Revenue)*Net Return Per sale = (10/(24+10+5))*7.6 = 1.95
(2nd Position2 Revenue/Total Revenue)*Net Return Per sale = (5/(24+10+5))*7.6 = 0.97
Double Check = (4.68+1.95+0.97) =  7.6
```

Comment: I couldn't understand this line--->`My less than 12 value is *0.6 of the revenue, my greater than 12 value is *0.6 of amount less than 12 and *0.4 of amount over.`

Comment: If the overall return per sale is above 12 I must apply a calculation like: 7.2+(((24+10+5)/3)-11)*.4)/3

Comment: Also,what is the formula for anount in your case???Is `amount=revenue*sales*units;`

Comment: return per sale = TotalRevenue/1stPosition Units

Comment: I am totally confused!!! Firstly, then what is the `amount` which you're to calculate! Secondly, in this `7.2+(((24+10+5)/3)-11)*.4)/3` expression, how did 7.2 came and how 11 was subtracted,it should have been 12!!! And, as per me formula for all the cases should be `return per sale = TotalRevenue/No. of Position Units;` and not only division by 1st Position Units!

Comment: Sorry Shekhar, 7.2 comes from .6*12, I meant to put -12 not -11.  Your suggestion would give us the amount of revenue per unit.  This number is not important to us.  We only consider a 1st position a sale so we only need to calculate an average of how much each sale is giving us. Thus, we divide by 1st position units only.

Comment: Can you explain the calculations you need to do more clearly? You say you want to "find how much revenue should be apportioned to each position towards the overall return per sale of 13" but I have no idea what that means or what the maths behind it is. Are you splitting that 13 between your three types somehow? What is the difference between a 1st Position and a 2nd Position? etc. At the moment it is very unclear what you are actually wanting here...

Comment: We are very close to solution,at last,please clear two things to me--->how 7.2 came in your example case and `My less than 12 value is *0.6 of the revenue, my greater than 12 value is *0.6 of amount less than 12 and *0.4 of amount over.` this statement! THIS STATEMENT IS HIGHLY AMBIGUOUS---how can one spit a number above 12 into number below 12 and number above 12!

Comment: The calculation im giving you is what determines how much we actually keep.  I then have to determine how much each of the positions contributed to that left over amount...

Comment: IF TotalRev/1st Position Units < 12
THEN TotalRev*.6
ELSE 7.2+(((TotalRev)/1stPositionUnits)-12)*.4)*1stPositionUnits

Comment: I added the answers to both of your questions to my original statement.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @user3749800-Still your formula in example was wrong,I am correcting it and on what basis you want to divide revenue? means,which formula must be used??? Can we arbitrarily divide it into the ratio of their revenues!

Comment: @shekharsuman - I have added an example of my attempt to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your question, I guess this should be OK in your case.

Assuming the variables are defined with the same name as they are in the question(e.g., rev_1st_pos,rev_2nd_pos1,rev_2nd_pos2,new_rev_1st_pos,new_rev_2nd_pos1,new_rev_2nd_pos2,net_rev,net_return_per_sale,unit_1st_pos)...

The usual meanings for all the variables are :-

1. rev_1st_pos=Revenue of 1st Position
2. rev_2nd_pos1=Revenue of 2nd Position1
3. rev_2nd_pos2=Revenue of 2nd Position2
4. new_rev_1st_pos=New Revenue of 1st Position after total calculation
5. new_rev_2nd_pos1=New Revenue of 2nd Position1 after total calculation
6. new_rev_2nd_pos2=New Revenue of 2nd Position2 after total calculation
7. unit_1st_pos=1st position Units
8. net_rev=Net Revenue calculated as shown below
9. net_return_per_sale=Net Return per sale as calculated below
10. check= a variable used to check final value equals the `net_return_per_sale`.

***Code :-***

```
total_rev=(rev_1st_pos+rev_2nd_pos1+rev_2nd_pos2);
if((total_rev/unit_1st_pos)>=12)
{
  net_rev=((((total_rev/unit_1st_pos)-12)*0.4)+(12*0.6))*unit_1st_pos;   // OR simply substitute (12*0.6) by 7.2
}
 else
{
 net_rev=total_rev*0.6;
}

net_return_per_sale=net_rev/unit_1st_pos;

new_rev_1st_pos=(rev_1st_pos/total_rev)*net_return_per_sale;
new_rev_2nd_pos1=(rev_2nd_pos1/total_rev)*net_return_per_sale;
new_rev_2nd_pos2=(rev_2nd_pos2/total_rev)*net_return_per_sale;

double check=new_rev_1st_pos+new_rev_2nd_pos1+new_rev_2nd_pos2;  // here check must be equal to net_return_per_sale
```

If there is still some issue,please leave a comment!